# how to use jquery validate to compare two dropdown value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two dropdown (start time & end time) that I want to validate using jquery validate, making sure the end time is greater than start time, but I can't get it to work.  It is always showing the error message no matter what I put.  Can someone please take a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[JSFIDDLE example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uVnQ4/12/)

```
<label for="start_time">Start Time:<font color="red">*</font></label>
            <select name = 'start_time_hour'>
                <option value = '10'>10</option>
                <option value = '11'>11</option>
                <option value = '12'>12</option>
            </select>
<label for="end_time_hour">End Time:<font color="red">*</font></label>
            <select name = 'end_time_hour'>
                <option value = '10'>10</option>
                <option value = '11'>11</option>
                <option value = '12'>12</option>
            </select>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("le", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value <= $(param).val();
    }, "less"); 
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("ge", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value >= $(param).val();
    }, "greater");  
$("#add").validate({
    event: "keyup",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        },
rules:{
        start_time_hour:{le: "#end_time_hour"},
    end_time_hour:{ge: "#start_time_hour"},
    },
messages:{
    start_time_hour:{le: "Must be less than end time"},
    end_time_hour:{ge: "Must be greater than start time"},
},
});
});
```

Comment: What is `event: "keyup"` supposed to be and/or do?  There is no such option for this plugin called `event`.  See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions  There's a `onkeyup:` option, but it's enabled by default and you'd only call it when you need to disable the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are mixing id attribute and name attribute.
Reference: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

By indicating # in a selector you are telling to select a single element with the given id attribute, but you are using the name attribute.

So for not reference a not existent id attribute, you have to change the rules code to:

```
rules:{
    start_time_hour:{le: "end_time_hour"},
    end_time_hour:{ge: "start_time_hour"},
    }
```

and your validator to:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("le", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value <= $("select[name="+param+"]").val();
}, "less"); 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ge", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value >= $("select[name="+param+"]").val();
}, "greater");
```

(look at the selectors)

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uVnQ4/13/

Comment: Hi Irvin, thanks a lot!
I found that it checks the first digit first, so "7" is greater than "15" because 7 is greater than 1.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, if the answer is correct mark it with the green mark; you are welcome!

Comment: Try parse your data into integer and check with that, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2KS5X/

Comment: Irvin, parseInt works!
Sorry, trying to make it more user friendly, is it possible to improve it so that when user selects 12 for start time, then selects 14 for end time, the user won't have to click on start time again to make the error message disappear?
example: http://jsfiddle.net/2KS5X/1/